# Why DisplayMember doesn't work with manually added DataRow in ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

Here is the thing I add manually few DataRow's to `this.listBox1.Items` and set in WinForms Designer the `DisplayMember` to column name but all I get displayed later is a list of type's name (System.Data...) .

How to solve this issue?

CODE:

```
list1.ForEach(x => this.listBox1.Items.Add(x)); //x is DataRow from a filled DataTable
```

Comment: Could you share code snippet?

Comment: Not much code its very simple. I edited my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` are applicable only when you use data binding (`ListBox.DataSource`). They work either with real properties, which can be retrieved by reflection, or via the .NET component model and the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` interface.

If you bind a `DataTable` directly, the `GetEnumerator` method and the `IList` implementation returns always `DataRowView` instances instead of `DataRow`s. `DataRowView` implements the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` where the `DisplayName` can refer a column name.

So if you want to add some custom filtered list, I suggest you to create one from whatever source. For example:

```
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
listBox1.ValueMember = "Value";

var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new {Name = i.ToString(), Value = i}).ToList();
listBox1.DataSource = list;
```

If `Name` property exists, you will see its value; otherwise, you will see the `ToString` of the items.

However, if you add the items programmatically (`ListBox.Items`), these properties are ignored and always the `ToString` of the items will be used.

Comment: I am not binding the datatable direcly. I insert each DataRow into the ListBox manually. DataTable is being filled by an adapter before I insert all DataRows into the ListBox. I want to work with DataRow and not with an anonymous type

Comment: Why don't you just bind the `DataTable` then? Or if you manually add the items why do you insist to the `DataRow` list instead of a string list or a custom type list with reasonable `ToString` method? `DisplayMember` is applicable only for data binding.

Comment: Then use a wrapper class around the `DataRow` type. The wrapper can return the underlying row and its `ToString` can return a correct value. Populate your list with the wrapper instances.

Comment: @devhedgehog Because `DataTable` / `DataRow` are not designed to be used for data binding. `DataView` / `DataRowView` are. The main problem in your case is that `DataRow` have no properties like a normal class, so you can't simply bind to it, and there is no supported syntax to bind to `dataRow[colName]`.

Answer (score 2):

Specify the column name you want to add to your list box:

```
list1.ForEach(x => this.listBox1.Items.Add(x["column_name"]));
```

Comment: list1.ForEach(x => this.listBox1.Items.Add(x["GroupName"])); works but selected item is later then an simple string and i need the complete row in order to work with another columns such as group id.

Comment: Do you _have to_ add the rows line by line? I guess binding the listbox would be clearer and easier to handle.

Comment: I have to. Its just the way it is.

Comment: Do you always have the same number of columns in your datatable?

Comment: Well then one way could be to add all the columns like `...Items.Add(x["c1"] + " " + x["c2"])` etc. or first creating a string like `string s = string.Format("{0} {1}", x["c1"], x["c2"]);` and then add it like `.Items.Add(s);`. But I'm not very happy with this solution...